# Perl on background when invoked from another env

Tags: perl, shell, backgrounding

I have a Perl script that is supposed to do some work on background. This is well described - I fork, kill (return 0) the parent and do the work in the child. When I run it directly from shell, it works as expected (i.e. returns to shell right after killing the parent and continues on background). But if I run it from another environment, e.g. from PHP via executing

```
    php -r "passthru('my-perl-script.pl')"
```

it returns to shell after the child is done. Any ideas why is this happening?

Thanks!

EDIT:
Here is the Perl code I was using:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

local $| = 1;

# fork the process - returns child pid to the parent process and 0
# to the child process
print ' [FORKING] ';
my $pid = fork();
error('Failed to fork: $@') and exit 1 if $@;

# exit parent
print ' [KILLING PARENT] ';
exit 0 if $pid;

# continue as child process
print " [CONTINUING AS CHILD] \n";

# wait 3 secs (for testing) and exit
sleep 3;
print " [DONE]\n";
exit 1;
```

Output when executed directly:

```
$ ./background-test.pl
 [FORKING]  [KILLING PARENT]  [KILLING PARENT]  [CONTINUING AS CHILD]
$  [DONE]
```

Output when executed via PHP:

```
$ php -r "system('./background-test.pl');"
$ [FORKING]  [KILLING PARENT]  [KILLING PARENT]  [CONTINUING AS CHILD]
  # ... 3 seconds wait ... 
  [DONE]
$
```

My question was why doesn't the Perl script disconnect when invoked from other environments (here PHP is just an example).

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a mininal runnable demonstration of the problem.

Comment: I added the sample Perl code I was using to demonstrate the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're saying that PHP is waiting for the grandchild to end even though the child exited.

`system` doesn't return since `php` collects the child's STDOUT, the same STDOUT that was inherited by the grandchild. On a Linux system, this can be seen by adding the following to the Perl script:

```
system("ls -l /proc/$$/fd");
```

From shell:

```
lrwx------ 1 ikegami ikegami 64 Jun  1 14:07 1 -> /dev/pts/0
```

From PHP:

```
l-wx------ 1 ikegami ikegami 64 Jun  1 14:08 1 -> pipe:[10052926]
```

Normally, when you deamonize a process, you reopen its STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR, redirecting them to `/dev/null` or to a log file.

```
open(STDIN,  '<',  '/dev/null') or die $!;
open(STDOUT, '>',  '/dev/null') or die $!;
open(STDERR, '>>', '/var/log/application.log') or die $!;
```

Normally, when you deamonize a process, you also call `POSIX::setsid()`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. System works in the same way, it returns to shell after the child process terminates.

Comment: Hmm seems that redirecting the STDOUT to /dev/null does the trick. Thanks!